# Are two entangled waves actually a single wave packet?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-entanglement

If two quantum particles are entangled they can no longer be fully described individually. The two of them together have only one wave equation.

Doesn't this mean that we are actually dealing with a single Siamese twin sort of thing?

I don't understand how, after entanglement, they can still be described as two separate entities. It seems like we're talking about one oddball wave packet that's being stretched out over great distances.

Hoping for some clarification here.

April 12 Comment:

OK, Thanks to all for your helpful comments and insights. I see now that the wave equation is not the actual particle itself but just the way its variable attributes evolve in time. So the single equation is just a description of the interconnectedness between the attributes of the two entangled particles.

I was pleased, though, to learn about the commonly misused (and singular) term 'biphoton'. Sounds a bit like my Siamese Twin description.

Now all I have to do is understand what entanglement is.

Comment: What do you want to know? Yes the two particles have a single (non separable) wave function. Yes, after measurement it can be described in term of (products of ) wavefunctions for each particle. Anything else is a matter of interpretation. You want to call them a single particle? Go for it, but be clear on what you mean and what you can test.

Comment: No, two quanta are not the same as one quantum. They require two irreversible energy transfers instead of one, which means that there are two classical systems and not just one. Entanglement is very confusing if you have the wrong mental model about "particles" as objects. In the correct mental model "quanta" are amounts of energy, more precisely, they are amounts of field energy. There is always one field. In the most simple scenario there is only enough energy in the field to extract exactly one quantum. In entanglement problems there are, at least, two quanta worth of energy in there.

Comment: Even if you wanna call it that, you'll have to say then that this "single particle" can "split" into two once the entanglement is broken... so it is not clear we would gain anything apart from a linguistic modification

Comment: "Are two entangled particles actually one particle?" No. This is not a physics question.

Comment: Are two brown bananas actually one banana?

Comment: I am waiting for your question to (hopefully) be re-opened to answer :-). I think the current answers lack defining the concepts at play here, which may lead to great confusion.

Comment: I'm 85 years old, so, no, it's not homework and no, I'm not asking for any work to be checked. I'm a total novice here (or close to it). So I apologize for not being clear. I recently read a couple of Scientific American articles that talked about entanglement and I got totally confused because of the way they were talking about the entities being two separate things while entangled.

Comment: Entangled is confusingly used by physicists and even more so in magazine articles.  Simplest example of entanglement is photon downconversion in a crystal, higher energy photon gets converted to 2 lower energy photons ... amazingly the photons get created with opposite polarizations .... this lead to a lot of baloney about faster than light information travel.  More complex, in Quantum computers we can entangle 2 very small circuits .... they are making an EM field together .... until one is read we don't know the state of the system.

Comment: "I don't understand how, after entanglement, they can still be described as two separate entities.". Nobody understands. Entanglement is a "shut up and calculate" thing.

Comment: The question is reopened, to make sure that it can't be reasonably answered.

Answer (score 2):

It is not unusual for a system of 2 entangled photons to be referred to as a "biphoton".  When the total photon count is known, as in such case, it is a Fock state.  When there is entanglement, as already mentioned, the component functions are not in a Product state and there is a single state consisting of 2 component photons.

The component photons do not really have individual identities at that point, although they are frequently discussed as if they do.  One may be identified as being in one place (headed to Alice), and the other being identified as being elsewhere (headed to Bob).  But they are more accurately described as a system of 2 particles.

And yes, such a system has spatiotemporal extent.

Comment: Every electromagnetic field has an extent. The actual problem is that while we are correctly teaching that photons are amounts of energy at the high school level, the way we teach QM 101 (non-relativistic quantum mechanics), then causes this false mental picture of quanta as "point particles" to emerge in students' minds. In reality all quanta are merely amounts of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges, and neither of these physical properties has "size". The "size" of the system in photonic entanglement is given by the location of the detectors. The field itself is everywhere.

Comment: @FlatterMann Completely agree.  Regarding entangled photon pairs specifically: the placement of the detectors can be such that there is no reference frame in which the detector clicks are local to each other.  

And in fact the entangled photons don't even need to co-exist at the same time.  One can be detected before the other is created (yes, that's pretty weird).  Which is why I used the term "spatiotemporal" extent.

Comment: One can trivially see that "distance" doesn't matter in the description of entanglement experiments: it doesn't show up anywhere. Whether the detectors are virtually in the same location or miles apart changes absolutely nothing... hence "the extent" is simply a complication in our imagination. The magic happens entirely in Hilbert "space"... which, of course, is nowhere. That's just a mathematical construct of ours.

Comment: Should have included this reference in my previous comment.  Entanglement Between Photons that have Never Coexisted (2012): https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4191 

Yes @FlatterMann, again I agree with what you are saying about distance not being a factor in entanglement.  The extent of the system does lead to some oddities when you consider "collapse", if there even is such a physical thing.  Specifically, when one of an entangled pair is measured, is the other still entangled?  No way to answer that... as you say: just another "complication in our imagination".

Comment: I usually urge people to forgo talking about "collapse". It's problematic for a number of reasons. What really complicates QM in my opinion is that the point-like event structure of classical physics is lost. A measurement is always an irreversible process, so we when we mean "quanta", we are talking about, at least world-lines or, worst case, entire future light cones being changed, with the caveat that that "change" is really only certain in the infinite future. We don't have good language to describe such a situation. Personally I even lack the intuition for it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I must express incredulity at how many downvotes your question got. I feel it is a valid question and am glad it got reopened.

Let us formally describe entanglement and then work towards a more physical interpretation of entanglement.

Let's say that you have two systems. For simplicity let
$$\text{System 1} \leftrightarrow \text{ Particle 1}$$

and
$$\text{System 2} \leftrightarrow \text{ Particle 2}.$$

By these arrows, I am essentially mapping one set of words (system 1) to another set of words (particle 1), so that when we say system 1 we equivalently mean particle 1 (and vice versa).

In textbook Quantum Mechanics, we represent systems with a special type of vector space known as a **Hilbert space**. Often, a Hilbert space representing a system is denoted by $\mathcal{H}$. Now, as you know systems can occupy certain **states** (e.g. a spin-1/2 particle can be spin up or spin down or some superposition of both states). Quite conveniently, the possible states of our system $\mathcal{H}$ are represented by the vectors that live in $\mathcal{H}$. Succinctly, $\lvert \psi \rangle \in \mathcal{H}$ is a state of $\mathcal{H}$. Now, there are actually stricter requirements on what a "state" is, but it's not so important for this discussion.

Let us apply these definitions to system 1 that we defined earlier. Concretely, $\mathcal{H}_1$ is a Hilbert space representing system 1. Equivalently $\mathcal{H}_1$ is a Hilbert space representing particle 1 (because particle 1 is system 1). Moreover, $\lvert \psi \rangle_1 \in \mathcal{H}_1$ represents a possible state that particle 1 can occupy.

Okay, so far we have outlined how to symbolically represent a system and states of a *single* system. What if we want to "combine" $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ into a composite system of both particles? After all, to see entanglement at all we need to consider a composite system!

Well, mathematically we can do this by taking the tensor product of the two Hilbert spaces
$$\mathcal{H}_{\text{tot}} = \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2.$$

Now, we call a state in $\mathcal{H}_{\text{tot}}$ **entangled** if it satisfies the following
$$\lvert \psi \rangle_{\text{ent}} \neq \lvert \psi \rangle_1 \otimes \lvert \psi \rangle_2.$$

In english, this definition amounts to something like, "An entangled state of a composite system composed of particle 1 and particle 2 is a state that cannot be represented by a state which allows us to make a measurement on particle 1 without impacting the result of a measurement on particle 2 in a predictable way."

Hence, given an entangled state of particle 1 and particle 2, we say that the measurements on particle 1 and particle 2 are **correlated**. This is the colloquial usage of the word "correlated" since we are saying my measuring of particle 1 impacts the outcome of a measurement on particle 2 in a predictable way.

*This is the meat of entanglement: correlation.* In particular, non-classical correlation.